# Why "missing parameter type error" when i run scala REPL in Flink with Java?

Tags: scala, apache-flink

When I run the flink scala REPL script in java cannot compile.

I tried this java code to run Flink scala REPL for test, bug always exception.

```
    Settings settings = new Settings();
    ((MutableSettings.BooleanSetting) settings.usejavacp()).value_$eq(true);
    IMain main = new IMain(settings, new PrintWriter(System.out));
    // Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(main.classLoader());
    for (String imp : imports) {
        main.interpret(MessageFormat.format("import {0}", imp));
    }
    ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment();
    String script = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("/opt/project/security-detection/sappo/src/sappo-interpreter/src/test/resources/demo.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    main.bind(new NamedParamClass("env", ExecutionEnvironment.class.getName(), env));
    main.interpret(script);
```

scala text

```
    val text = env.fromElements("Who's there?", "I think I hear them. Stand, ho! Who's there?")

    // result 1
    val counts = text.flatMap { _.toLowerCase.split("\\W+") filter { _.nonEmpty } } map { (_, 1) } groupBy(0) sum(1)
    counts.print()

    // result 2
    val counts = text.map((x:String) => 1)
    counts.print()

    // result 3
    text.print()
```

result 1

```
    import org.apache.flink.core.fs._
    import org.apache.flink.core.fs.local._
    import org.apache.flink.api.common.io._
    import org.apache.flink.api.common.aggregators._
    import org.apache.flink.api.common.accumulators._
    import org.apache.flink.api.common.distributions._
    import org.apache.flink.api.common.operators._
    import org.apache.flink.api.common.operators.base.JoinOperatorBase.JoinHint
    import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions._
    import org.apache.flink.api.java.io._
    import org.apache.flink.api.java.aggregation._
    import org.apache.flink.api.java.functions._
    import org.apache.flink.api.java.operators._
    import org.apache.flink.api.java.sampling._
    import org.apache.flink.api.scala._
    import org.apache.flink.api.scala.utils._
    import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._
    import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time._
    env: org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment = Local Environment (parallelism = 8) : ee335d29eefca69ee5fe7279414fc534
    console:67: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x$1.toLowerCase.split("\\W+").filter(((x$2) => x$2.nonEmpty)))
           val counts = text.flatMap { _.toLowerCase.split("\\W+") filter { _.nonEmpty } } map { (_, 1) } groupBy(0) sum(1)
```

result 2

```
    import org.apache.flink.core.fs._
    import org.apache.flink.core.fs.local._
    import org.apache.flink.api.common.io._
    import org.apache.flink.api.common.aggregators._
    import org.apache.flink.api.common.accumulators._
    import org.apache.flink.api.common.distributions._
    import org.apache.flink.api.common.operators._
    import org.apache.flink.api.common.operators.base.JoinOperatorBase.JoinHint
    import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions._
    import org.apache.flink.api.java.io._
    import org.apache.flink.api.java.aggregation._
    import org.apache.flink.api.java.functions._
    import org.apache.flink.api.java.operators._
    import org.apache.flink.api.java.sampling._
    import org.apache.flink.api.scala._
    import org.apache.flink.api.scala.utils._
    import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._
    import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time._
    env: org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment = Local Environment (parallelism = 8) : 5cbf8e476ebf32fd8fdf91766bd40af0
    console:71: error: type mismatch;
     found   : String => Int
     required: org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.MapFunction[String,?]
           val counts = text.map((x:String) => 1)
```

result 3

```
    import org.apache.flink.core.fs._
    import org.apache.flink.core.fs.local._
    import org.apache.flink.api.common.io._
    import org.apache.flink.api.common.aggregators._
    import org.apache.flink.api.common.accumulators._
    import org.apache.flink.api.common.distributions._
    import org.apache.flink.api.common.operators._
    import org.apache.flink.api.common.operators.base.JoinOperatorBase.JoinHint
    import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions._
    import org.apache.flink.api.java.io._
    import org.apache.flink.api.java.aggregation._
    import org.apache.flink.api.java.functions._
    import org.apache.flink.api.java.operators._
    import org.apache.flink.api.java.sampling._
    import org.apache.flink.api.scala._
    import org.apache.flink.api.scala.utils._
    import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._
    import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time._
    env: org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment = Local Environment (parallelism = 8) : ee335d29eefca69ee5fe7279414fc534
    Who's there?
    I think I hear them. Stand, ho! Who's there?
    text: org.apache.flink.api.java.operators.DataSource[String] = org.apache.flink.api.java.operators.DataSource@53e28097
    PASSED: testIMain
    PASSED: testIMainScript
```

Comment: I'm not an expert in flink... but it looks like you are trying to execute **Scala** code in a **Java** _interpreter_ - that would explain the error message. BTW, my main clue for that is this `"org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment"`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Yes,this is a import error ~ thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Scala REPL that comes with Flink:

```
$ bin/start-scala-shell.sh local
```

I tried the three examples you shared (with Flink 1.7.0), and they all worked just fine.

Comment: thanks,i try to design a dynamic scala script interpreter and i has finded the problem.
btw, scala repl shell is worked in flink 1.7.0 for scala 2.11, but flink 1.7.0 for scala 2.12 in apache mirror is not import the org.apache.flink.api.FlinkIloop in flink-dist-*.jar, so run script throws class not found exception, i think is a bug.